# Searching user in directory services in very slow

Tags: 2007, active-directory, user

When adding a user to a  SharePoint site, **searching that user in directory services is taking more time than usual**, in some cases more than a minute. 
Is there any specific reason for this? Can the response time be reduced??
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will be something to do with this KB article usually: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970612

SharePoint doesn't like read only controllers.

[STSADM command here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263452%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is when i try to find users from address book/directory services. People picker is working fine.

Comment: Oh righto :) Good luck then!